# Perform different action as per facebook login status

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I want to do is as per the user come on my page,

1. checking facebook status. if logged in and already authorized with my app then redirect to new page i.e. `url.php`.
2. If not logged in and already authorized then show the page `index.php` with `connect facebook` button
3. If not authorized with my app then ask him to do. Also ask to remember the password so that next time he login, should be redirected to page `url.php`

I tried with `FB.getLoginStatus`. When I execute simple code as below, it works fine:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

When I tried to do same with following actual code it never succeed, after bunch of try.
Actually what happens, `the content on the page like`button`and rest it always get loaded even user is logged in or not.`
Please give me some hint for this code to place the condition appropriately:

Mycode:

```
<?php
session_start();
$appId = '178862'; 
$appSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'dev01.dev/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/';  //path to script folder
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <title>ThenWat</title>
    <script>
 function AjaxResponse()
 {
    //alert("2");
    var mydata;         
    CallAfterLogin(mydata, function(send) {
               });
  } 
function LodingAnimate() //Show loading Image
{
    //alert("animate4");    
  //  $("#LoginButton").hide(); //hide login button once user authorize the application
}

    </script>
</head>
<body style="height: 560px">
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
?>
    <div style="z-index: 1; left: 538px; top: 290px; position: absolute;"> 
    <input class="uibutton confirm large" type="submit" value="Connect with facebook" onclick="AjaxResponse()" > 
    </div>
<?php
}
?>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: '<?php echo $appId; ?>',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
//  channelUrl: '<?php echo $return_url; ?>channel.php',
    oauth: true});};
(function() {
        //alert("1");
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());
function CallAfterLogin(data,callback){
        //alert("CallafterLogin3");
        FB.login(function(response) {  //---
    x:    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        {
            LodingAnimate(); 
            FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) {
            console.log(mydata);
              if(mydata.email == null)
              {
                 alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                 ResetAnimate();
              }           
              else 
        {
            //alert("json-5");
            var json = JSON.stringify(mydata.movies.data);
        //    alert(mydata.movies);
            var a = JSON.parse(json);       
            $.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a}, function(data) 
            {
                $.ajax({
            url:'url.php'
            ,async:     true
            ,cache:     false
            ,dataType:  'html'
            ,success:   function(data){
                $('body').html(data);
                    }
        });        
            });
        }

              }); //--
         } //if
             }); //---
          } //main function
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put `AjaxResponse()` in onload then it does not enter in line `x`

before `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {` if I put `document.getElementById("b1").style.display="none";` it hides button

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Perform user App authentication.
2. Store user facebook profile details in database
3. If user has already authenticated your app, and logged into his facebook a/c the redirect to next page
4. If user is not logged in, SDK will ask to perform facebook login
```

source code

fb login
        
        
        
        
        
        
        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
        
        
            .middle{
                background-color:Yellow;
            }

```
        .left{
            background-color:Green;
        }
        .url{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: block;
        }
        .url:hover {
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        }
        .header{
            background-color: #61B329;
            color: #FFF;
            margin-top: 0px !important;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 9px;
        }
        .page-header-text {
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin: 0px;
        }


        html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 }
    </style>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function()
        {
            console.log( "ready!" );
            //alert("Welcome");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-header header">
        <h1 class="page-header-text">login</h1>
    </div>      
        <table border = "0" width = "100%">
            <tr>
                <div class = "middle">
                    <td style = "width:40%">
                    <input type = "button" id = "loginButton" class = "btn btn-primary" onclick = "authUser();" value = "Login | Facebok" style = "display:none; left:500px; margin-top:200px; position:relative"/> 
                    </td>               
                </div>
            </tr>               
        </table>
    <div id = "fb-root"></div>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var userid;
        FB.init({
        //appId: '',
        appId: 'app id',
        xfbml: true,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(checkLoginStatus);
        function authUser() 
        {
            FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope:'email'});
        }
        function checkLoginStatus(response) 
        {               
            if(response && response.status == 'connected') 
            {
            FB.api('/me?fields = movies,email,name,gender,locale,location,link', function(mydata)
            {
                console.log(mydata.email);
                console.log(mydata.id);
                userid = mydata.id;
                var name = mydata.name;
                gender = mydata.gender;
                locale = mydata.locale;
                city = mydata.location;
                link = mydata.link;
                //alert(name);
                var email = mydata.email;
                //var json = JSON.stringify(mydata.movies.data);
                //var a = JSON.parse(json);
                var picture = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+userid+"/picture?type = small";
                // alert(picture);
                $.post('user_record.php',{ name: name, email: email, userid:userid, picture:picture, gender: gender, locale: locale, city: city, link: link}, function(data)
                {
                    var $form = $("<form id = 'form1' method = 'post' action = 'start.php'></form>");
                    $form.append('<input type = "hidden" name = "userid" value = "'+userid+'" />');
                    $('body').append($form);
                    window.form1.submit();
                });
            });

            console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>   
</body>
```

Source code on GIthub : https://github.com/karimkhanp/facebookLoginSDK